# What does lint_package_filename_pkgname_match mean?

Tags: application-development

I've submitted an app to the click store, but it comes back with this message:-

```
lint_package_filename_pkgname_match
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily happen if you don't pay attention to the namespace you specify in

1. the web UI of the software store and
2. the manifest file of your app

Sometimes it's just a small typo, like in the following example.

```
e.g. com.ubuntu.developer.rick-rickspencer3.franglish' != 'com.ubuntu.developer.rick-rickspencer3.Franglish' from DEBIAN/control"
```

In the future the software store will do this automatically and extract the namespace from the the manifest.